# Pdf2image library of Python throws "No font in show/space" error

Tags: python, poppler, pdftoppm, poppler-utils

For a few pdfs the pdf2image library throws this error. I have set `strict=True` in the convert_from_path method and hence I am getting these syntax errors

I think it means that my system doesn't have the required fonts but is there any other way to solve this issue?

I believe it's actually a poppler issue and but I haven't been able to find anything on it.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
pg_img = convert_from_path(pdf_path, dpi=calculated_dpi, first_page=i + 1, last_page=i + 1, fmt='jpeg',
                                           jpegopt={"quality": 100, "progressive": True, "optimize": True}, strict=True)
                pg_img[0].save(os.path.join(img_folder_dir, file_name+"_"+str(i) + ".jpg"), format='JPEG', quality=85)
```

This is the error:
"Syntax Error (1077): No font in show/space
Syntax Error (1117): No font in show/space
Syntax Error: Unknown font tag 'F5'
"

Comment: @KJ thanks for replying. If I keep that parameter to False then I get images with blank lines. I installed the necessary fonts and it resolved some errors but do you know how to resolve this "No font in show/space error"?

Comment: Can you tell post your tried code and an example of what result you want ?